# Solr: Setting defaultSearchField in schema not supported since Solr 7

Tags: debugging, solr, ckan

**Describe the bug**

When trying to add a Solr core with the CKAN schema.xml on Solr I get an error:

Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': Unable to create core [new_core] Caused by: Setting defaultSearchField in schema not supported since Solr 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CKAN version 2.9**

Describe the bug

When trying to add a Solr core with the CKAN schema.xml on Solr 8 you will get an error:

Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': Unable to create core [new_core] Caused by: Setting **defaultSearchField** in schema not supported since Solr 7

[image]

CKAN schema.xml includes
text

### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to the schema.xml file, in my case its found here `/var/solr/data/ckan/conf/schema.xml`
2. Then, `sudo nano  /var/solr/data/ckan/conf/schema.xml`
3. Change

   text

to

```
<df>text</df>
<solrQueryParser q.op="AND"/>
```

**Note**: The defaultSearchField parameter in the schema is no longer supported. Use the df parameter instead. This option had been deprecated for several releases.